# Cannot View Traces in S3-compatible object store

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, trace

I have this Django application that I have successfully instrumented with opentelemetry and have configured to send traces to an opentelemetry collector in my Kubernetes cluster. Also, I configured the collector to send the traces to grafana tempo which worked; I can even view the traces in Grafana. But the thing is, the storage backend I am using for Tempo doesnt have the traces sent to tempo in it. Perhaps, tempo isn't sending the traces to the storage backend. How can I resolve this.

This is my collector config:

```
mode: "deployment"

config:
  receivers:
    otlp:
      protocols:
        grpc:
          endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4317
        http:
          endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4318

  processors:
    batch:
      timeout: 10s
      send_batch_size: 1024

  exporters:
    debug: {}
    otlp:
      endpoint: grafana-tempo:4317
      tls:
        insecure: true

  service:
    pipelines:
      traces:
        receivers: [otlp]
        processors: [batch]
        exporters: [debug, otlp]

resources: 
  limits:
    cpu: 250m
    memory: 512Mi
```

And this is my Grafana Tempo config:

```
server:
  http_listen_port: 3100


distributor:
  receivers:
    otlp:
      protocols:
        grpc:
        http:


ingester:
  trace_idle_period: 5s  
  max_block_bytes: 512000
  max_block_duration: 10s  

storage:
  trace:
    backend: s3
    s3:
      access_key: 7HGA...
      secret_key: lO7..
      endpoint: objectstore.lon1.civo.com/tempo
      bucket: tempo
      insecure: true
```

I tried to configure an ingester in my tempo config, but still the same.